# How to only instantiate a dependency when required

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I have the class bellow:

```
class Foo {

    protected $dependency;

    function __constructor(Dependency $dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }

    function get($name = null)
    {
        if(is_null($name))
            return $this->dependency->get();

        return $name;
    }
}

new Foo(new Dependency);
```

The problem is that I instantiate the dependency even when it's not needed.

How do i instantiate the dependency only when needed?

Comment: So you only want to inject the dependency if `$name` is `null` inside of the `get()` method?

Comment: Yes. I just want to inject the dependency when $name is null, and still applying inversion of control.

Comment: Then take it out of the constructor (spelt `__construct()` in PHP and put it in the `get` method.

Comment: Or use setter injection.

Comment: I will be in the same situation but in a different function using a setter or a the get function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really know whether `Foo` will need the dependency or not at the time you instantiate `Foo`, hence at the time you inject the dependency. If you want a lazy dependency, you can move that complexity into one of two places:

1. Move the late instantiation into `Foo`. For that `Foo` will need some sort of factory/service locator/dependency injection container that allows `Foo` to get an instance of `Dependency` when it needs it. E.g.:

   ```
   public function get($name = null) {
       if (is_null($name)) {
           return $this->dependencyFactory->getInstance()->get();
       }
   }
   ```

   Cons: `Foo` needs to be aware of this complexity.
2. Make `Dependency` lazy internally. Whatever `Dependency` does that uses resources, delay that until `Dependency::get` is called the first time.

   Pros: other components need not be aware of this behaviour and can keep using the class as before.

Comment: Yes! Lazy Load Using a Container is the solution for my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using constructor injection you should use setter injection so that you will set the injection class when needed

Comment: Can you give me some code so i can understand better?

Comment: Note that this means that some *external* code outside `Foo` needs to know *when* `Foo` needs the dependency. That spreads out the logic which was formerly contained just within `Foo::get`.